# how to get custom xml values in android?

Tags: android, xml, custom-attributes

I want to get the number of launcher:cellWidth in xml:

```
<mobi.intuitit.android.p.launcher.CellLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:launcher="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/mobi.intuitit.android.p.launcher"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    launcher:cellWidth="80dip"
/>
```

I know that I can get it in a Custom view by:

```
public CellLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CellLayout, defStyle, 0);

        mCellWidth = a.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.CellLayout_cellWidth, 100);
```

But how Can I get it in a Activity? not a Custom view.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom view should have a getter `CellLayout.getCellWidth()` and from your `Activity`, after finding you can get its value.

```
CellLayout cellLayout = (CellLayout)findViewById(R.id.cell_layout);

cellLayout.getCellWidth();
```

Comment: Maybe I can use a xml parser, but it's more complex. Thanks!